# Node does not wait for loop to complete

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, asynchronous, es6-promise

I have tried async/await & using promises however I cannot get this code to execute in order.

The code iterates through a document and parses it before saving it to an array, then saving the array to .json file.

The code continues to run before the loop finishes however which means it writes an empty file as the parsing has not been completed.

Turning it into an async function to await does not solve the issue. Nor does returning a promise and then using .then() to execute final code. It still runs straight away.

```
    const fs = require('fs');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const mammoth = require("mammoth");

const articleFolder = './Articles/';
var allArticles = [];

const extractDocuments = async () => {
    let files = fs.readdirSync(articleFolder);
    for(const file of files) {
        await convertToHTML(file);
    }
    completedExtraction();
}

async function convertToHTML(filename) {
    var filepath = articleFolder + filename;
    mammoth.convertToHtml({path: filepath})
    .then(function(result){
        let html = result.value; // The generated HTML
        let messages = result.messages; // Any messages, such as warnings during conversion
        updateArticles(filename, html);
    })
    .done();
}

function updateArticles (filename, html) {
    var article = {
        file: filename,
        content: parseHTML(html)
    }
    allArticles.push(article);
}

function parseHTML (html) {
   let $ = cheerio.load(html);
   let title = $('h3').first().text();
   let date = $('h3:eq(1)').text();
   $('h3').slice(0,2).remove()
   let content = $('body').html();
   let parsedArticle = {
       title: title,
       date: date,
       content: content
   }
   return parsedArticle;
}


function completedExtraction() {
    fs.writeFile('./articles.json', JSON.stringify(allArticles), (err)=>{
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('File Written.');
    });
    console.log('Finished.');
}
extractDocuments();
```

Comment: `convertToHTML` neither uses `await` anywhere nor returns anything explicitly. So `await`-ing it doesn't do anything useful. You most likely need `return mammoth.convertToHTML/* ... */`

Comment: with that said, I'm suspicious of the `updateArticles(filename, html);` call. Seems like it's potentially problematic as it's also not really explicitly waited for. Just kind of/sort of happens in sequence by accident of the `.then()`. The biggest problem is that it updates a global variable. This should likely just return the article and do the operation in `Promise.all()`

Answer (score 0):

To solve with map I would do something similar to:

```
const extractDocuments = async () => {
    let files = fs.readdirSync(articleFolder);
    const articlePromises = files.map(async file => {
       const html = await convertToHTML(file)
       return {
           filename: file,
           html: html
       }
    })
    allArticles = await Promise.all(articlePromises)
    completedExtraction();
}

async function convertToHTML(filename) {
    var filepath = articleFolder + filename;
    return mammoth.convertToHtml({path: filepath})
    .then(function(result){
        let html = result.value; // The generated HTML
        let messages = result.messages; // Any messages, such as warnings during conversion
        return html
    })
    .done();
}
```

So to wrap up `extractDocuments` uses a map to iterate and create articles. `convertToHTML` only returns the created HTML and nothing more. We no longer use the `updateArticles` since this is now handled in the `extractDocuments`

Hopes this helps a bit. Hope it points you in the right direction

Comment: No, forEach is not async-aware and will not wait. For loops, on the other hand, are a syntactic construct and can support serial execution in order. This is misleading and should be corrected to avoid confusing beginners about how callbacks and forEach work.

Comment: You are right about that @RobertKawecki, I removed that section